# My iteration is taking forever. Looking for a better way

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, nested-loops

Given a set of sixteen letters and an English dictionary file, need to find a solution where those sixteen letters can fit into a 4x4 grid so that a valid word can be read across each row, and down each column.

My current solution:

1) Get a list of all of the possible 4-letter words that can be made with those letters (anagram generator) and assign them to an array.

2) Loop through each word, trying it in every row, while checking that the correct number of each letter is used.

3) Checking if the word created in each column exists in the anagram array.

The logic works, but it's been running over an hour and I'm on word 200 of the 400+ array of anagrams.  Any suggestions?

```
namespace GridWords
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] words = new string[] { "zoon", "zonk", "zone", "zona", "zoea", "zobo", "zero", "zerk", "zeal", "zack", "rore", "roon", "rook", "rood", "rone", "role", "roke", "roed", "rode", "rock", "roch", "robe", "roar", "roan", "road", "rhea", "rend", "redo", "reck", "rear", "rean", "real", "reak", "read", "raze", "rare", "rank", "rand", "rana", "rale", "rake", "rade", "rack", "rach", "race", "raca", "orzo", "orra", "orle", "ordo", "orca", "oral", "orad", "ooze", "oner", "once", "oleo", "olea", "olde", "okra", "okeh", "ohed", "odor", "odea", "odal", "odah", "oche", "obol", "oboe", "nork", "noob", "nook", "nolo", "nole", "noel", "node", "nock", "nerk", "nerd", "neck", "near", "neal", "naze", "nark", "nare", "nard", "narc", "nala", "nada", "nach", "nabk", "nabe", "lorn", "lore", "lord", "loor", "loon", "look", "lone", "loke", "lode", "loco", "lock", "loch", "loca", "lobo", "lobe", "loan", "load", "leno", "lend", "lehr", "lech", "lear", "lean", "leak", "lead", "lazo", "laze", "larn", "lark", "lare", "lard", "lank", "lane", "land", "lana", "lakh", "lake", "laer", "lade", "lack", "lace", "krab", "kore", "kora", "kond", "kolo", "kola", "kohl", "koel", "kobo", "koan", "knob", "knar", "khor", "khan", "kern", "kerb", "keno", "kbar", "karn", "kara", "kaon", "kane", "kana", "kale", "kaed", "kade", "horn", "hore", "hora", "hoon", "hook", "hood", "honk", "hone", "hond", "holk", "hole", "hold", "hoke", "hoer", "hoed", "hock", "hobo", "hoar", "hero", "hern", "herl", "herd", "herb", "hend", "helo", "held", "heck", "hear", "heal", "head", "haze", "haro", "harn", "harl", "hark", "hare", "hard", "hank", "hand", "halo", "hale", "hake", "haka", "haen", "haed", "hade", "hack", "haar", "eorl", "eoan", "enol", "elan", "ecod", "echo", "ecad", "ebon", "earn", "earl", "eard", "each", "dzho", "drek", "drab", "doze", "dorr", "dork", "dore", "door", "dool", "dook", "doob", "done", "dona", "dole", "doer", "doen", "doek", "dock", "doab", "dhal", "dhak", "dern", "deco", "deck", "dear", "dean", "deal", "daze", "darn", "darl", "dark", "dare", "darb", "dank", "dale", "dahl", "dace", "daal", "czar", "cred", "cran", "crab", "coze", "corn", "cork", "core", "cord", "coon", "cool", "cook", "conk", "cone", "cond", "cole", "cold", "cola", "coke", "coho", "coed", "code", "coda", "coal", "clon", "clod", "clan", "clad", "chon", "chez", "cher", "char", "chao", "chal", "chad", "cero", "carr", "carn", "carl", "cark", "care", "card", "carb", "cane", "calo", "calk", "cake", "cade", "caba", "broo", "brod", "brer", "bren", "bred", "bran", "brae", "brad", "bozo", "born", "bork", "bore", "bord", "bora", "boor", "boon", "bool", "book", "booh", "bonk", "bone", "bond", "bona", "bolo", "bole", "bold", "bola", "boko", "boke", "boho", "bode", "bock", "boar", "boak", "bloc", "bled", "blah", "blae", "blad", "bhel", "berk", "bend", "beck", "bear", "bean", "beak", "bead", "barn", "bark", "bare", "bard", "bank", "bane", "band", "banc", "balk", "bale", "bald", "bake", "bael", "bade", "back", "bach", "baal", "azon", "azan", "arna", "arle", "ared", "area", "arco", "arch", "arba", "arar", "arak", "anoa", "ankh", "ance", "anal", "aloe", "alod", "alec", "albe", "alba", "alar", "alan", "alae", "aked", "ahed", "aero", "aeon", "adze", "acre", "acne", "ache", "acer", "aced", "able", "abed", "abac" };
            char[] letters = new char[] { 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'h', 'k', 'l', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'r', 'z' };
            for (int z = 0; z < words.Length; z++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(z);
                for (int y = 0; y < words.Length; y++)
                {
                    bool letterCountCorrect0 = true;
                    char[] wordLetters0 = words[z].ToCharArray().Concat(words[y].ToCharArray()).ToArray();
                    for (int a = 0; a < wordLetters0.Length; a++)
                    {
                        if (countInstances(wordLetters0, wordLetters0[a]) != countInstances(letters, wordLetters0[a]))
                        {
                            letterCountCorrect0 = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (y != z && letterCountCorrect0)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < words.Length; x++)
                        {
                            bool letterCountCorrect1 = true;
                            char[] wordLetters1 = words[z].ToCharArray().Concat(words[y].ToCharArray()).Concat(words[x].ToCharArray()).ToArray();
                            for (int a = 0; a < wordLetters0.Length; a++)
                            {
                                if (countInstances(wordLetters0, wordLetters0[a]) != countInstances(letters, wordLetters0[a]))
                                {
                                    letterCountCorrect1 = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (x != y && x != z && letterCountCorrect1)
                            {
                                for (int w = 0; w < words.Length; w++)
                                {
                                    bool letterCountCorrect2 = true;
                                    char[] wordLetters2 = words[z].ToCharArray().Concat(words[y].ToCharArray()).Concat(words[x].ToCharArray()).Concat(words[w].ToCharArray()).ToArray();
                                    for (int a = 0; a < wordLetters0.Length; a++)
                                    {
                                        if (countInstances(wordLetters0, wordLetters0[a]) != countInstances(letters, wordLetters0[a]))
                                        {
                                            letterCountCorrect2 = false;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (w != x && w != y && w != z && letterCountCorrect2)
                                    {
                                        char[] row1 = words[z].ToCharArray();
                                        char[] row2 = words[y].ToCharArray();
                                        char[] row3 = words[x].ToCharArray();
                                        char[] row4 = words[w].ToCharArray();
                                        char[] wordLetterArray = row1.Concat(row2).Concat(row3).Concat(row4).ToArray();
                                        Array.Sort(wordLetterArray);
                                        if (wordLetterArray == letters)
                                        {
                                            string col1 = new string(new char[] { row1[0], row2[0], row3[0], row4[0] });
                                            if (col1 != words[z] && col1 != words[y] && col1 != words[x] && col1 != words[w])
                                            {
                                                string col2 = new string(new char[] { row1[1], row2[1], row3[1], row4[1] });
                                                if (col2 != words[z] && col2 != words[y] && col2 != words[x] && col2 != words[w])
                                                {
                                                    string col3 = new string(new char[] { row1[2], row2[2], row3[2], row4[2] });
                                                    if (col3 != words[z] && col3 != words[y] && col3 != words[x] && col3 != words[w])
                                                    {
                                                        string col4 = new string(new char[] { row1[3], row2[3], row3[3], row4[3] });
                                                        if (col4 != words[z] && col4 != words[y] && col4 != words[x] && col4 != words[w])
                                                        {
                                                            if (words.Contains<String>(col1.ToLower()) && words.Contains<String>(col2.ToLower()) && words.Contains<String>(col3.ToLower()) && words.Contains<String>(col4.ToLower()))
                                                            {
                                                                Console.WriteLine(new string(row1) + " " + new string(row2) + " " + new string(row3) + " " + new string(row4));
                                                                //Console.WriteLine(col1.ToString() + " " + col2.ToString() + " " + col3.ToString() + " " + col4.ToString());
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static int countInstances(char[] arrToSearch, char charToFind)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < arrToSearch.Length; x++)
            {
                if (arrToSearch[x] == charToFind)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example, as requested:

Given the letters "N, O, O, and T" find a solution where these letters fit into a 2x2 grid so that when read across and down, English words can be created.  The answer would be:

```
T O
O N
```

Except this problem is for a 4x4 grid.

UPDATE: Thanks for your help, but I'm an idiot. I didn't fix my copy/pasted variables (which, I suppose, goes back to the guy who suggested I refactor). Also, the way I was comparing arrays was faulty. Fixed these issues and ran against known working word list, worked like a charm.  Ran again against my original data, took 13 seconds. No results. Thanks again for your help.

UPDATE 2: Since I don't have enough rep to answer my own question, here is my working code (...code deleted...see dasblinklight's answer below)

UPDATE 3: Please see dasblinkenlight's answer below. Much more elegant, fewer loops. Thanks!

Comment: OW MY EYES IT BURNS! http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/extract-method

Comment: **Seven** nested `for` loops certainly will take a long time...

Comment: Do you need to find *one* solution or *all possible solutions*? Are you guaranteed that there is at least one solution, or is that to be determined by the algorithm?

Comment: can u give an example of the problem you are trying to solve??Given a set of sixteen letters and an English dictionary file, need to find a solution where those sixteen letters can fit into a 4x4 grid?? I guess you are actually trying to find the dictionary words from a 4 letter permutation?In that case you will only get 1 match in dictionary for every 4! permutations, that explains why it takes so long, you are doing a brute-force for all permutations, matching it against dictionary words, pls show an example, so that we can suggest an optimized solution. Thanks

Comment: One thing that I'd suggest as a meta-help, so to speak, is that you break chunks of that conditional logic into separate methods/classes.  It's very hard to reason about code that looks like that, even if you wrote it.  I think you'll find that the exercise alone will help you to see places where you may be able to optimize.

Comment: I know this is dirty, and I started to use recursion so it wasn't so deep, but this was a puzzle that was posed and I was just trying to drum up a quick and dirty solution. No, not homework, just a puzzle on a blog. All possible solutions would be great if there are more than one.

Comment: Also do you want this solutions only for 4 letter words and 4X4 grid, or do you want it to scale to find a word of any length???

Comment: @rao_555: I think the question is clear: "need to find a solution where those sixteen letters can fit into a 4x4 grid so that a valid word can be read across each row, and down each column"

Comment: Only 4-letter words apply. Yes, it is brute force, but some logic is added so that it skips words that use too many letters, words that have already been used, etc.

Comment: Clean up the code and use the VS Refactor functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to nest seven levels, all you need is five: four loops to try all four-way combinations of words that fit in the 16-letter set, and an extra loop to check the four vertical combinations implied by the choice of the horizontal words.

You need an efficient way to manage the set of letters that you are currently using. One way to deal with it would be creating an array of counters, like this:

```
static readonly int[] Counts = new int[256];
static void Add(string s) {
    foreach (var c in s) {
        Counts[c]++;
    }
}
static bool Sub(string s) {
    var res = true;
    foreach (var c in s) {
        res &= --Counts[c] >= 0;
    }
    if (!res) {
        Add(s);
    }
    return res;
}
```

`Sub(string)` tries to "subtract" the word from the counts, and returns `true` if it succeeds. `Add(string)` adds the word back to the counts.

Now you can write a four-way nested skeleton of your code, like this:

```
foreach (var w0 in Words) {
    if (!Sub(w0)) continue;
    foreach (var w1 in Words) {
        if (!Sub(w1)) continue;
        foreach (var w2 in Words) {
            if (!Sub(w2)) continue;
            foreach (var w3 in Words) {
                if (!Sub(w3)) continue;
                // Check if the w0..w3 combination yields four valid words
                // when you read it vertically, and restore the state
                Add(w3);
            }
            Add(w2);
        }
        Add(w1);
    }
    Add(w0);
}
```

The check of vertical words adds the fifth and the last nesting level. I converted words to a hash set to speed up the check:

```
var allExist = true;
for (var i = 0; allExist && i != 4; i++) {
    vert[0] = w0[i];
    vert[1] = w1[i];
    vert[2] = w2[i];
    vert[3] = w3[i];
    allExist = Words.Contains(new string(vert));
}
if (allExist) {
    found = true;
    Console.WriteLine(w0);
    Console.WriteLine(w1);
    Console.WriteLine(w2);
    Console.WriteLine(w3);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You can find [this program on the pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VASzPtcY). It finishes in several minutes on my computer without producing a solution. I verified that it finds solutions when they exist, though (when you comment out `Words` and `Letters` and uncomment the last two lines, the program finds both the valid combination and its transposed image).

Comment: Fantastic. I went to the question asker with this information in hand and he admitted he may have taken some liberties with his word choice, in that one was the name of a frustum-shaped chocolate with caramel center. I added "rolo" to the word list and this returned:

    arch
    bozo
    elan
    dork

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 10):

Use a backtracking algorithm.

Start by reading my series of articles on how to use a backtracking algorithm to solve the graph colouring problem:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/graph+colouring/

You do not have exactly the same problem, but it is *very* close.

Here's what you do. Suppose the grid is

```
11 12 13 14
21 22 23 24
31 32 33 34
41 42 43 44
```

You start with your sixteen letters: IDNVJGIEKGEESSSO, say.

make a guess as to what goes in 11. Say, I.

That now constrains what can possibly go in 12 and 21. Only those letters from words that begin with I and have a second letter from the remaining letters DNVJGIEKGEESSSO can be in 12 and 21. That enormously constrains the problem.

Now make a guess for 12. Say, D. That then constrains 13 and 22, further constraining the problem.

Now make a guess for 21, say, N, which constrains 22 (again) and 31.

Now make a guess for 22. It can't be V, J or G because no words begin NV, NJ or NG. Maybe it is I...

Keep doing that until you either find a solution, or you end up in a situation where there is no possible solution. If there is a solution, you're done.  If there is no possible solution given the guesses you've made, you must **backtrack to the previous guess** and make a *different* guess until all possible guesses are exhausted. Then backtrack *again*. And so on.  The key is to *lower the number of possibilities for each guess quickly*.

Comment: When you say "make a guess", is it faster to loop through the remaining letters and see if they make the first two letters of a word, or to do a find for the first two letters in the array? Doesn't a find also loop as well, so I'm not gaining anything? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Since I already have a word list, and I don't need to check every letter combination, I'm thinking I can use what you're saying and do a check after the second row.  If I tried "snow" in the first row and "fine" in the second, I can immediately exit this word combination, as no word starts with "sf". I'll let you know what kind of improvement, if any, I see. Thanks again.

Comment: @SlightlyA.: Your proposal will not give up as fast as Eric's, so in some cases it will be less efficient.  E.g., if you have a lot of words that start with S-N but it is impossible for the first two letters to be S, N, then you will end up testing all of those words instead of testing only S and N.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing would be to reduce the nesting if possible.

If that is not possible you should at least try to break out as much heavy stuff from the loops as possible.
The first thing that comes to my mind is all `.ToCharArray()` things. Precalculate `word.ToCharArray()` for each `word` in `words` and store them i a new array `char[][] wordCharacterArrays`. Then you save lots of calculation.

Also break out all `col1.ToLower()` etc to just below each definition, like

```
  string col1 = new string(new char[] { row1[0], row2[0], row3[0], row4[0] });
  string col1Lower = col1.ToLower();
  if (col1 != words[z] && col1 != words[y] && col1 != words[x] && col1 != words[w])
  {
      string col2 = new string(new char[] { row1[1], row2[1], row3[1], row4[1] });
      string col2Lower = col2.ToLower();
```

etc and reuse those values later to save lots of repeating calculations here too.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes down to things, this is simply a 16 character permutation. So you will have some ordering of characters

```
 abcd efgh ijkl mnop
```

The square is really almost a misnomer here. In addition to each 4 letter grouping, the n-th character of each grouping must also form a word. So instead of trying to place letters into boxes, which would be a waste of time, you could instead start forming permutations based on the input, and this kind of thing can be parallelized. Given your set of anagrams, it's a quick set based operation to find those permutations that contain no grouping that is an anagram. Once a candidate is found, then you can inspect the n-th characters for words. Continue in this fashion until the n-th character match works.

Once a match is found, then you can write the string into a 2d array.

Comment: 16! is too big a number: his nested loops would likely finish faster.